# Remove both duplicates based on multiple (but not all) columns

Tags: r, dplyr, duplicates, distinct

I want to remove both (all) sets of duplicate rows within a dataframe, where rows are duplicated by some but not all columns.

The below comes close to what I want, but it requires the entire row to be duplicated, not just certain columns (variables).

```
df[!(duplicated(df) | duplicated(df, fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```

How would I modify the code to specify columns/variables, as can be done with the distinct function?

```
df.unique <- distinct(df, var1, var2, var3)
```

Answer (score 2):

If we have a set of columns, select those columns to subset the data

```
nm1 <- paste0("var", 1:3)
df[!(duplicated(df[nm1]) | duplicated(df[nm1], fromLast = TRUE)), ]
```